# Adaptive Payments

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

We allow our customers to create invoices using our app, and then send them to their clients to be paid.

The current payment options we offer are stripe and offline payment.

We want to add PayPal as a payment method too.

Adaptive payment seems like the only way to do this, but it is no longer available?

*I've had a business PayPal account for over 6 years. 
* Our app is [plutio.com](https://plutio.com)

Answer (score 0):

If you could apply for an APP ID from below page, you are still able to create invoice via PayPal Adaptive Payments.

https://www.paypal-apps.com/user/my-account/applications
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/invoicing/?mark=invoicing

And besides, PayPal has provided new REST API for invoicing. Please check below page for its details.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/invoicing/